# if else nesting in stored procedures

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with if-else statements. i have a scenario where i need a need if else statement inside else statement. i have done this in c# but i need it in sql server since i'm pretty much new to stored procedures.
lemme provide a sample snippet for u ppl.

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_getstore_details](@input varchar(100))
as 
begin
    declare @out varchar(100)
    declare @result int

    if(LEN(@input)=2)
        begin
          --select  statement here.
        end
    else if (@input like '%[0-9]%')
        begin
          --select statement here 
        end
    else 
        begin
            set @result=(len(@input) - len(replace(@input, ',', '') )
            if(@result>1)
                begin
                  --select statement here 
                end
            else
                begin
                  --select statement here
                end
        end
end
```

Thanks in advance for ur help

Comment: Apart from one too many `(` in this statement `set @result=(len(@input) - len(replace(@input, ',', ''))` it looks fine to me. Change to `set @result=len(@input) - len(replace(@input, ',', ''))`. Also you can't just have a comment in a `begin...end` but I guess that you actually have some code in there.

Comment: s of course i ve a select statement depends on the condition

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getstore_details]
@input VARCHAR(100)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @out VARCHAR(100) 
    DECLARE @result INT 

    IF LEN(@input) = 2 
    BEGIN 
        --select  statement here. 
    END 
    ELSE IF @input LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
    BEGIN 
        --select statement here  
    END 
    ELSE  
    BEGIN 
        SET @result = LEN(@input) - LEN(REPLACE(@input, ',', '')) 
        IF @result > 1
        BEGIN 
            --select statement here  
        END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            --select statement here 
        END 
    END 
END
```